# How to read the text file or XML file using pure JavaScript and using no other library or framework

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to read the text file or an XML file but I am stuck.

How to pass the file name that I have to read. Once I get the contents of the file I am sure I will need to use regex but I am stuck on getting the file name and data inside it.

I am sure how to do this in jQuery, but I need to try this out using pure JavaScript and nothing else. Any pointers or suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: Where is the file you want to read? Is it on the client's machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to reliably read a filename using JavaScript only, due to security reasons.  Even JQuery will fail at some point (Google Chrome tends to block Ajax calls to the local machine).

EDIT: An example of a JSON config object:

```
var config =
{
    color: "blue",
    time: "15:00",
    amount: 1,
    names: ["Bob", "John"]
}

var someName = config.names[1] //John
```

Comment: I know that... My concern is if I have a config file generated at runtime & I have to load the data from it and display on browser, how will I read the file? I can do it in jquery, but I want to try this out in native javascript only

Comment: You could store the config as a .js file and simply load it (before launching the code that uses it) as any other external js file.  If needed, create a new <script> element in the <head>

Comment: Okay, so how would I parse it, or read it...Can you show me a small example of it. Lets say the data is

Vertical Align
thumbnail 1: images/hi.jpg
image 1: images/img-hi.jpg
caption 1: "Hi"
.
.

& so on... How will I read it, or use this??

Comment: this was of great help though, atleast I got to know I can use the config file as .js...

Comment: I've edited the answer to show an example.  JSON is perfect for this.